# Ag grid enterprise row model server side queries

Tags: ag-grid

How we can I handle ag-Grid filtering, sorting, grouping, column grouping at back-end using PostgreSQL database. Can someone help me on this? I have already tried ag-Grid MySQL example and still it is working perfectly.

Comment: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-enterprise-mysql-example  here i have tried but its not works

Comment: any progress on this?